# Show the First Post from Each of 3 Different Post Types on a Web Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I have 3 different custom post types: 1.) `"events"`, 2.) `"winners"` and 3.) `"offers"`. How would I go about retrieving the first (latest) post in each of these post types on a single web page (i.e a home page).

Would I use `get_posts()` or would I have to manipulate `the_loop()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) is the safest way to use multiple loops. It does not mess up with the original query.

Another way would be to create new WP_Query objects:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Note: [Why you should not use query_posts()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts)

Comment: So should i use get_posts() or WP_Query()? What way would you recommend?

Comment: get_posts() uses WP_Query(), so I personally prefer the later. I find it more powerful, more flexible,...

Comment: get_posts() worked a treat in conjunction with setup_postdata()

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@dotty:**

The answer from *@sorich87* is correct, but I thought I'd elaborate a bit.  I've coded a class for you called *(verbosely)* `LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery` and you can use it in [**the loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in place of `WP_Query`, like so:

```
<ul>
<?php $args = array('post_type'=>'events,winners,offers'); ?>
<?php $query = new LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery($args); ?>
<?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
  <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Below is the code for the `LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery` class which you can copy into your theme's `functions.php` file *(or use the code in a plugin if you like.)* The nice thing about this alternative to `WP_Query` is it does a *single query* to the database instead of *one for each of the three post types* like you'd be forced to use when using `WP_Query()` directly.

```
<?php
class LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery extends WP_Query {
  var $flag;
  function __construct($args=array()) {
    $this->LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery($args);
  }
  function LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery($args=array()) {
    if (isset($args['post_type']) && !is_array($args['post_type']))
      $args['post_type'] = explode(',',$args['post_type']);
    $this->flag = true;
    parent::query($args);
  }
  static function on_load() {
    add_filter('posts_join',array(__CLASS__,'posts_join'),10,2);
  }
  static function posts_join($join,$query) {
    if (isset($query->flag)) {
      global $wpdb;
      $join .=<<<SQL
INNER JOIN (
SELECT post_type,MAX(post_date) AS post_date
FROM {$wpdb->posts}
GROUP BY post_type) max_date ON 
  max_date.post_type={$wpdb->posts}.post_type AND 
  max_date.post_date={$wpdb->posts}.post_date
SQL;
    }
    return $join;
  }
}
LatestPostPerPostTypeQuery::on_load();
```

I've also posted [**a standalone file on Gist**](http://gist.github.com/613011) allowing you grab the source code and drop the  example into a file in the root of your website to call it directly from the browser to watch it in action:

- [*latest-post-per-post-type-query.php*](http://gist.github.com/613011)